# Arduino won't recognise a 5v input

Tags: c, input, arduino

I am very new to programming. I am writing a program, for an Arduino clone. I have a 12V coil relay, that works off an 12V IR switch. The relay has picked up 5V from the Arduino, and will supply 5V to pin 1, when the relay is switched EG something moving in front of the IR switch.

The program seems to ignore the incoming 5V, and continues the program as though it wasn't even trying to read it.

When I check on the serial monitor, what the pin is reading (high or low), it just shows "xxx" when there is nothing present, and doesn't react when my hand signals the switch.

I am sure it is some basic C++ code syntax error.

Code below:

```
void loop() {
  analogWrite(channel_a_enable, 255);
  //turns feeder motor on through H bridge, to feed brass case
  digitalWrite(channel_a_input_1, HIGH);            
  digitalWrite(channel_a_input_2, LOW);
  val = digitalRead (sensor_ir_pin);
  //reads IR switch and checks if it has a case present yet
  Serial.println(val);
  if (val = HIGH)
  //if brass case rolls past sensor, switching IR switch and relay
    analogWrite(channel_a_enable, 0);
    //turns feeder motor off
  digitalWrite(channel_a_input_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(channel_a_input_2, LOW); 
  current_potent = analogRead(A0);
  //reads the potentiometer setting (set for a max of 15 seconds time)      
  delay(current_potent * 14.6627);
  //delays, while the brass case is in the flame, getting annealed. Also provides the multiplier for 15000 mill seconds into 1023 read point on the potentiometer
```

Comment: In the line `if(val = HIGH)`, `=` probably should be `==`.  Also, if there are no braces after the if statement, the next line will only run if the condition is true, but subsequent lines will run even if it is false.

Comment: I doubt the software is the problem.  Rather Suggest checking source of 5v to assure it is always available.  Then checking to assure 5v is getting to relay contacts.  Then checking that 12v is getting to IR switch.  Then checking th 12v is switched off/on/off when moving hand infront of IR sensor.

Comment: Also make sure there's a resistor from pin1 to 0V. 10K or less.